# I am trying to return some results in an array for rest api I am only able to return a single value as values are being overide in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

```
function get_all_activity_by_category(){

    $id = $this->input->get('id');

    $data['activity_category'] = $this->users_model->single_activity_category($id);

    $activity_category = $data['activity_category'];

    $data['activities_by_category'] = $this->users_model->list_of_activities($id);

    $activities_by_category = $data['activities_by_category'];

    foreach($activities_by_category as $activity)

        $activity_id = $activity->activity_id;



    $data['activity_session'] =  $this->users_model->search_sessions_by_activity($activity_id);


    $activity_session = $data['activity_session'];



    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');



     return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('activity_category'=>$activity_category,'activity'=>$activities_by_category,'activity_session'=>$activity_session),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));


  }
```

I want results in array for session and venues but I am getting empty array, I have implemented the code for sessions and venues but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: `foreach()` could do with some `{}`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is data to be stored and that you want `$activity_session` to be a list of the sessions, your `foreach` loop was just looping over the id's and leaving `$activity_id` with the last value.  You should use this to build up a list of sessions...

```
    $activity_session = array();
    foreach($activities_by_category as $activity)  {
        $activity_session[] =  $this->users_model->search_sessions_by_activity($activity->activity_id);
    }
```

Comment: typo `foreach`.

Comment: @smith thanks - it's early and caffeine hasn't kicked in yet :(

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this has helped, please consider marking it as answered.